# Makefile Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")

Tags: makefile

I have the following script in Makefile which is giving me the error

after entering make start-test, The script should run command locust -f tests/load/ if .env file is present else it should not run the command.

```
start-test:
# Check if .env file exists
        ifeq ($(wildcard $(.env)),yes)
            include .env
# If the file doesn't exist, execute this rule
        all:
            echo ".env file does not exist"
        else
# If the file exists, execute this rule
        all:
            echo ".env file exists"
            locust -f tests/load/
        endif
```

Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")

Comment: `ifeq`, `include`, etc. are **makefile** constructs.  That means they cannot be indented with a TAB: everything indented with a TAB is part of the rule's recipe and the rule's recipe is passed to a POSIX shell to run; the POSIX shell doesn't understand `ifeq` etc.

Comment: @MadScientist so how can I implement the if else clause as part of Makefile script. Thanks

Comment: I think you're supposed to be using ifeq in this syntax instead; ifeq ($(wildcard .env),)

Comment: You should first describe what exactly it is that you want this makefile to do.  You can't create a rule inside of another rule (e.g., you can't "nest" an `all` target "inside" a `start-test` target--that's not how make works).

Comment: @MadScientist The script should run command locust -f tests/load/ if .env file is present else it should not run the command. This is what I want to achieve in the scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the description in the comment, you can do this:

```
start-test:
        if test -f .env; then locust -f tests/load/; fi
```

This will work on any system which provides a POSIX shell.